# Can someone ID this part, a 1xY plate with an inverted slope?

Tags: part-identification

I am trying to ID this part. It is the upside down triangle part that seems to be linked to a tile.

[image: LEGO part]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you are seeing one end of 2 of [Part 52501 Slope, Inverted 45 6 x 1 Double with 1 x 4 Cutout](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=52501&name=Slope,%20Inverted%2045%206%20x%201%20Double%20with%201%20x%204%20Cutout&category=%5BSlope,%20Inverted%5D#T=S&C=85&O=%7B%22color%22:%2285%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D) in Dark Bluish Grey.

[image]